# For arbitrary vector, $v \frac{dv}{dt} = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{ \frac{dv}{dt} }$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

$$v \frac{dv}{dt} = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{ \frac{dv}{dt} }$$

I came across this identity that I'm unsure how to prove. The convention is that $v=|\vec{v}|$.

If I write $$v=(a,b)$$

then $$ \vec{v} \cdot \vec{ \frac{dv}{dt} } = aa'+bb' = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} (a^2 +b^2) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}v^2 = v \frac{dv}{dt}.$$

But out of curiosity, I tried to do the calculation differently, by explicitly writing $$v=\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}$$
Then multiplying the two yields an ugly root:

$$v\frac{dv}{dt}=\sqrt{(aa')^2 + (bb')^2 + (a'b)^2 + (b'a)^2}$$

How does this simplify further to get the answer I'm looking for. I'm missing something really obvious here.

Comment: $\mathrm dv/\mathrm dt\ne\sqrt{a'^+b'^2}$. What you have there is $|\mathrm d\vec v/\mathrm dt|$.

Comment: Oh man. Of course. Thanks for the anwsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, $$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{2aa'+2bb'}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ thus $$v\frac{dv}{dt}=aa'+bb'=\vec{v}\cdot{\frac{d \vec v}{dt}}$$